# Formset inside a ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

So lets try to explain:

I have a model called inventory, which serves to handle my products and their quantity. And I have another model that I would ask to do a certain service and would need to inform how many products and their quantity would be needed to complete that same service.

My problem is, I am using a ModelForm to render my form, but with this I just can select one product in the field items(that is a foreignkey of Inventory) and can't inform how many items would be needed. So, I'd like something to my user select one or more products from my inventory and inform how many them he will need to complete de service. I read about formset and seems to be what I need, but i can't figure out how to put in my code, or inside of my actually modelForm.

inventory models:

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    name= models.Charfield(max_lenght=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ......
```

service models:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    items = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    description = models.TextField()
    date= models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    ....
```

views:

```
class CreateServiceView(CreateView):
    model = Service
    form_class = ServiceModelForm
    template_name = 'service/create_service.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('service:list_service')
```

template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post">
    {%csrf_token %}
    <table class="table">
        {{ form }}
    </table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="service:list_service">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I need to change this field to something which I would select the item and put the quantity.

[image: Items from my inventory]

Answer (score 0):

Based on how you named your variable `items` with a "s", I derive that you mean to use the same service for multiple inventories, right?

In that case you cannot use `items = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, ...)` in `Service`. Rather use `service = models.ForeignKey(Service, ...)` in `Inventory`.

This way every Inventory object is related to exactly one Service object. You can then access all the inventory-objects of a specific service by doing `service.inventory_set.all()`

Comment: More information [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/)

Comment: Really, A service would be related to one or more service, a need to change the relation ship to ManyToManyField I guess. But what I need to do is select a item from my inventory and informe also the how many of these items I will need, because after I need to subtract the item selected of the quantity of my inventory, I don't know if I were clear. I update my question

Comment: I'm not sure I understood: `A service would be related to one or more service` ?

But if what you mean is that you don't know in advance how many services you'll have for one Inventory object, that's not a problem for the template. You can use django's builtin template tags (like: {% for service in services %} after you have passed the services as context). More on this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for)